# Sentence with no verbs

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

> There seeming to be no hopes of their being taken off.

Do you consider this as a correct sentence? If it is correct, where is the main verb? And why has **to be** been used in this case?

Sorry, no context is available. You may add other words as your wish to make it a complete sentence.

Comment: Did you phrase this sentence on our own ? If not, can you give us a little more context, maybe the source

Comment: This sounds like a **subordinate clause**, something is missing. What is the outcome of there being no hope?

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what the sentence was suppose to mean. 
You can change the phrase into:

> There seems to be no hope of them taking off.

First Sentence:

Subject: `them`

Phrasal verb: `taking off` and `hope`

Adjective: `no`

or

> Their taking off seems to be hopeless.

Second Sentence:

Subject: `Their`

Phrasal verb: `taking off`

Adjective: `hopeless`

In both cases you have a complete sentence.

Comment: You have given two complete sentence, construction of which are not familiar to me. Please break down these sentences and make them easy.

Comment: @NazmulHassan In what format would you like it to be broken down?

Comment: Usage of "to be hopeless" and "to be no hope of". Do they both mean same? "to be of no hope of" has taken a object, where "to be hopeless" didn't take any object. Why? Are there rules for them? I would be happy if you agreed to help me. Thanks for nice answer.

Comment: @NazmulHassan "to be hopeless" would be the same as "to be of no hope". When you say "There seems to be no hope of" the following would be what there is no hope about. It could be " them eating ice-cream" or "him going to bed". You can also use the phrase "There seems to be no hope" by itself when answering a question such as "Is there a chance he'll wake up on time?".  In the second sentence, when i said "hopeless "it means "without hope" which is an adjective. We also have a phrasal verb, being "taking off". The taking off is for a group of people not including yourself, which is why it is

Comment: their. so you have a pronoun, a verb and an adjective. therefore a complete sentence.

Comment: @NazmulHassan I updated the answer, hope if helps